# that running boy

Tags: adjectives, present-participles

a. Stop that running boy!

b. Stop that boy running!

You see a young boy running towards a street and you think he is going to try and cross it and put his life in danger. You shout to other people to stop the kid before it is too late.

Which of the sentences is grammatically correct?
Which is natural?

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatically correct. In (a), *running* identifies the boy, in (b) it identifies the action you want to put a stop to.

In real life, with a busy road nearby I think the situation would be obvious to bystanders and you would only need to shout "Stop that boy!" If you must include *running*, possibly (b) is more likely (but that's opinion-based.)

Comment: I'd have also gone with b. But it is true, in panic you use the least words possible.